# Linux software for simulating reinforced concrete slabs and walls

Tags: linux, simulation, design

I'd like to be able to simulate some concrete slabs and walls and to calculate their resistance to different loads in different points based on the thickness, reinforcement and hardness.

Ideally the software should update the maximum load in real time when I change one of the values mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

[SkyCiv](https://skyciv.com/structural-software/s3d-structural-analysis-software/): runs in the cloud, so can run on Linux. But it is not free.

[Estru3D](https://sourceforge.net/projects/estru3d/): runs on Linux and is open-source.

[Midas Software](https://en.midasuser.com/index.asp): Trial version can be downloaded [here](https://en.midasuser.com/download/main.asp). But can't recall if they have Linux version.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [CAST3M](http://www-cast3m.cea.fr/) developed by colleagues at CEA could be relevant. There is a Linux version. I don't know if it is open source or not.

You could contact me by email at office (at [CEA, LIST](https://www-list.cea.fr/)) to `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr` for more.